# Fetch data with pymysql (DictCursor)

Tags: python, pymysql

It seems like a really simple task but I'm having difficulties doing it proper.

My SQL Query look like this:

```
self.link = self.db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor);
self.link.execute("SELECT * FROM crawler_data WHERE id=%d" % id_crawl)
```

And I want to access the columns by the following:

```
row = self.link.fetchall()
if row["address"]:
    self.address = self.filterAddress(row["address"])
```

I get the error `"list indices must be integers, not str"`.

When I print the `row` I get the following structure returned:

```
{u'address': 'Address Value', u'domain': 'Domain Value'}
```

How do I access the "address" string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the case above I was trying to select only 1 result (`WHERE id=:%d`), and then check if it had `address` set. To do this, it is not a good idea to use `self.link.fetchall()` because that returns a list with all results that can be used in a loop for example.

The correct function to use is `self.link.fetchone()` which only return the dictionary. If you use:

```
row = self.link.fetchone()
```

then you can also use

```
print row["key"]
```

If you use

```
row = self.link.fetchall()
```

then you have to use

```
print row[0]["key"]
```

Answer (score 4):

The results of the fetchall() will be a list of dictionairies. In your example, access the string by

```
results = self.link.fetchall()
row = results[0]
self.address = self.filterAddress(row["address"])
```